# I can't run the Python Flask application, help needed

Tags: python, flask

When I run this Flask application logs in console seem to be fine, but I cannot find my webpage by the default url.
Error: Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. I entered this URL : http://127.0.0.1:5000/ with the trailing slash.
Any thoughts?

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hello, World! <h1>Hello, World!<h1>"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = False)
```

[image: code and console log are on this screenshot]

[The error webpage looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6758.png)

Comment: So what URL did you enter?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:5000/

Comment: Have you tried literally copying & pasting the address, like `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`? The trailing slash might matter

Comment: Ahh, man. It still won't work. All the same. I tried it with the trailing slash too

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the screenshot, the webserver is running. Just go to your browser and type in the search bar:

```
localhost:5000
```

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, it raises the same error. And the same 404 Error Not Found Web-page.

Comment: Well, just try to open with trailing slash 
`http://localhost:5000/`